# Does set variable modify variable values across threads?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Say I have a function `foo`

```
void foo () {
    bool block = true;
    while(block) {}
}
```

And I have 5 threads running this function, all blocked in the `while` loop.

If I attach gdb to this process, and jump over to one of these 5 threads, and do the following

```
(gdb) set variable block=false
```

My question is what is the full effect of the above set variable statement?

Does it change the value of `block` to `false` on all threads, or just the current thread in gdb? Does running the above statement unblock only one or all of the 5 threads stuck in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it change the value of block to false on all threads, or just the current thread in gdb?

Just the current thread. You have 5 separate and *independent* stack variables named `block`; it is unreasonable to expect GDB to change more than one of them.

> Does running the above statement unblock only one or all of the 5 threads stuck in the while loop?

It follows that only one thread will be unblocked.

If you want an ability to unblock all threads at once, make the variable global (and `volatile`, since you are going to be modifying it from "outside" of the program).

P.S. Your spin loops are going to burn a lot of CPU, and compiler is allowed to compile them out. Inserting a `usleep()` for short duration may help with both problems.